# Iphone Videoplayer

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating video based ios application.I am using MPMoviePlayerController for playing video. It is working correctly for local video files but I am not able to play the video for the server link please give me some idea

Here is my code

```
MPMoviePlayerController * player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageName];

player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
[player setContentURL:url];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want using a `MPMoviePlayerController` implement that server links or streaming.

refer a this sample code. Will help you a lot: [MoviePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html)